# Encountering UnsatisfiedLinkError in Nimbus logs when running Apache Storm 2.4.0 on Mac M2 Pro (JDK 8, Rosetta Terminal)

Tags: macos, scala, apache-storm, rosetta

Can anyone advise how to fix this Nimbus error log I am encountering when trying to start Apache Storm 2.4.0 (I'm running on Mac M2 Pro, Rosetta terminal, JDK 8). Consequently, I am getting (org.apache.storm.utils.NimbusLeaderNotFoundException: Could not find leader nimbus from seed hosts [192.xxx.xx.xx]. Did you specify a valid list of nimbus hosts for config nimbus.seeds?
) on the Storm UI

Error log snippet:

Caused by: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: /private/var/folders/g1/10fw1w0d1cn7c4xm8_509y9c0000gn/T/librocksdbjni8669833958421657998.jnilib: dlopen(/private/var/folders/g1/10fw1w0d1cn7c4xm8_509y9c0000gn/T/librocksdbjni8669833958421657998.jnilib, 0x0001): tried: '/private/var/folders/g1/10fw1w0d1cn7c4xm8_509y9c0000gn/T/librocksdbjni8669833958421657998.jnilib' (mach-o file, but is an incompatible architecture (have 'x86_64', need 'arm64')), '/System/Volumes/Preboot/Cryptexes/OS/private/var/folders/g1/10fw1w0d1cn7c4xm8_509y9c0000gn/T/librocksdbjni8669833958421657998.jnilib' (no such file), '/private/var/folders/g1/10fw1w0d1cn7c4xm8_509y9c0000gn/T/librocksdbjni8669833958421657998.jnilib' (mach-o file, but is an incompatible architecture (have 'x86_64', need 'arm64'))
at java.lang.ClassLoader$NativeLibrary.load(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_372]
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary0(ClassLoader.java:1934) ~[?:1.8.0_372]
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:1817) ~[?:1.8.0_372]
at java.lang.Runtime.load0(Runtime.java:782) ~[?:1.8.0_372]
at java.lang.System.load(System.java:1100) ~[?:1.8.0_372]
at org.rocksdb.NativeLibraryLoader.loadLibraryFromJar(NativeLibraryLoader.java:78) ~[rocksdbjni-5.18.4.jar:?]
at org.rocksdb.NativeLibraryLoader.loadLibrary(NativeLibraryLoader.java:56) ~[rocksdbjni-5.18.4.jar:?]
at org.rocksdb.RocksDB.loadLibrary(RocksDB.java:64) ~[rocksdbjni-5.18.4.jar:?]
at org.rocksdb.RocksDB.(RocksDB.java:35) ~[rocksdbjni-5.18.4.jar:?]
at org.apache.storm.metricstore.rocksdb.RocksDbStore.prepare(RocksDbStore.java:67) ~[storm-server-2.4.0.jar:2.4.0]
at org.apache.storm.metricstore.MetricStoreConfig.configure(MetricStoreConfig.java:33) ~[storm-server-2.4.0.jar:2.4.0]
at org.apache.storm.daemon.nimbus.Nimbus.(Nimbus.java:542) ~[storm-server-2.4.0.jar:2.4.0]
at org.apache.storm.daemon.nimbus.Nimbus.(Nimbus.java:479) ~[storm-server-2.4.0.jar:2.4.0]
at org.apache.storm.daemon.nimbus.Nimbus.(Nimbus.java:473) ~[storm-server-2.4.0.jar:2.4.0]
at org.apache.storm.daemon.nimbus.Nimbus.launchServer(Nimbus.java:1535) ~[storm-server-2.4.0.jar:2.4.0]
at org.apache.storm.daemon.nimbus.Nimbus.launch(Nimbus.java:1560) ~[storm-server-2.4.0.jar:2.4.0]
at org.apache.storm.daemon.nimbus.Nimbus.main(Nimbus.java:1565) ~[storm-server-2.4.0.jar:2.4.0]

Looks like a compatibility issue. Any suggestions how to fix this?

Comment: Try using native JDK/JRE versions instead of Rosetta based version?